# Hover not working in Stacked Bars of FlotChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Could someone please help me with my problem.
Hover is not working in FlotChart.

Could you please check on the following codes?

```
function loadGraph(){
    //Display graph
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), ds, {
        grid:{
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            borderWidth : 0,
            margin : 10
        },
        xaxes: [ { ticks:ticks, rotateTicks: 0} ],
        yaxes: [ {  min: 0,
                    labelWidth : 40,
                    tickFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) 
                    {   
                        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                    },
                 }
                ],
        y2axis: { tickFormatter : charLang, tickLength : 10 },
        legend: { show: true, container: "#legendholder" }
    });
}

$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) { 
        alert("hey!");
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stacked Bar Chart's Hover not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673625/stacked-bar-charts-hover-not-working)

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle or other working example with actual data.

Comment: This is already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673625/stacked-bar-charts-hover-not-working